# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 - Flutter

Tags: function, for-loop, flutter

I have the simplest set of code which does not seem to be working on Flutter. It is a simple for loop, which seems to be giving the exception.

```
List vendorMainCategory = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
List testList = [];
List testList1 = [];

testFunction () {

testList1 = vendorMainCategory
print(testList1)

for(int i =0; i<4; i++){

testList[i] = testList1[i]

   }
}
```

As can be seen in the console, the function runs until the 'print(testList1)' line, and encounters an error as soon as the loop begins. Can't seem to figure out why this might be. Any help will be highly appreciated.

On calling this function using a FlatButton's onPressed property, I am shown this in the console:

```
I/flutter ( 5687): [one, two, three, four]
E/flutter ( 5687): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] 
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 5687): #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:72)
E/flutter ( 5687): #1      List.[]= (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:5)
E/flutter ( 5687): #2      _TestPage1State.newFunction (package:fetchapp/pages/test_page1.dart:80:16)
E/flutter ( 5687): #3      _TestPage1State.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fetchapp/pages/test_page1.dart:109:29)
E/flutter ( 5687): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:14)
E/flutter ( 5687): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter ( 5687): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 5687): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter ( 5687): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter ( 5687): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:470:9)
E/flutter ( 5687): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 5687): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter ( 5687): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 5687): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter ( 5687): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 5687): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 5687): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter ( 5687): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter ( 5687): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter ( 5687): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
E/flutter ( 5687): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
E/flutter ( 5687): W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5687): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5687): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
D/Surface ( 5687): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e08d6d000,api=1)
D/Surface ( 5687): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e08d6d000,api=-1)
D/Surface ( 5687): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e15bfa000,api=1)
V/PhoneWindow( 5687): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@9a76da, this = DecorView@897370b[MainActivity]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to try using `add`?

```
List vendorMainCategory = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
List testList = [];
List testList1 = [];

testFunction () {

testList1 = vendorMainCategory;
print(testList1);

for(int i =0; i<4; i++){

testList.add(testList1[i]); //<--changed to add

   }
}
  testFunction();
print(testList); //[one, two, three, four]
```

Comment: Okay, that works as a perfect answer. And now I'm getting the desired answer when I print testList . Thank you soooo much for this! xD

Could you throw more light on why the method used by me above does not work and throw that exception? Because I don't see any logical flaw with that. And if the code is followed to the line, we should get the desired result, even using that method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough of a reputation for it to show that I upvoted your answer, but I did. Really appreciate it. Please clarfy this further if you can. Cheers! :)

Comment: According to your subquestion please read more about list in dart... for example here is quite good page https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-lists

Comment: Right! Done. Thanks for that info too.